# Как закрыть родительскую форму из дочерней?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как я могу перезагрузить (закрыть и открыть) родительскую форму из ее дочерней?

У меня есть окно **Form2**, оттуда я открываю окно **Edit**

```
Edit ed = new Edit(rowIndex, rowNumber);
ed.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
ed.Location = this.Location;
ed.ShowDialog();
```

Как вы видите, **Form2** не закрывается, а **Edit** открывается просто поверх всего.

А позже я хочу, чтобы при нажатии определенной кнопки у меня окно **Edit** закрывалось, а окно **Form2** перегружалось, но я не знаю, как это можно реализовать.

Вот так я закрываю окно **Edit**:

```
this.Close();
```

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: "Как закрыть parent Form из child Form" и в тоже время "А позже я хочу, чтобы при нажатии определенной кнопки у меня окно Edit закрывалось, а окно Form2 перегружалось,...", т.е. вы хотите все таки закрыть дочернее, а не родительское?

Comment: Я хочу закрыть дочернее окно, а родительское "перезагрузить". Дочернее окно у меня закрывается, но как перезагрузить родительское - не знаю.

Comment: @Nephilim после `ed.ShowDialog();`  добавь `this.Refresh();`

Comment: @DIlshod нет, не работает(

Comment: Можете метод в родителе сделать и вызывать его в дочернем окне

Comment: Еще вот такой вариант имеется  `Application.Restart();`. Думаю это то что ты ищешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто небольшой примерчик.

[image: пример работы]

Вот кодбихайнд формы редактирования

```
public partial class EditForm : Form
{
    private BindingSource _bsPerson = new BindingSource();

    public EditForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //привязки
        SetBindings();

        //устанавливаем роли для кнопок
        this.CancelButton = buttonCancel;
        this.AcceptButton = buttonOK;

        //кнопка ОК отдает нужный результат
        buttonOK.Click += (s, e) => this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Установка привязок
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBindings()
    {
        _bsPerson.DataSource = typeof(Person);

        textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsPerson, nameof(Person.FirstName));
        textBoxLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsPerson, nameof(Person.LastName));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Редактируемый чел
    /// </summary>
    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get => _bsPerson.Current as Person;
        set
        {
            _bsPerson.Clear();
            _bsPerson.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

А вот главная форма

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private BindingSource _bsPeople = new BindingSource();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //привязки
        SetBindings();
        //загрузка данных
        LoadData();

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.Text = "Пример";

        this.buttonEdit.Click += ButtonEdit_Click;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Установка привязок
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBindings()
    {
        _bsPeople.DataSource = typeof(List<Person>);

        dataGridViewPeople.DataSource = _bsPeople;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка данных
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadData()
    {
        //получаем список людей из БД
        List<Person> people = Program.Context.GetPeople();

        _bsPeople.Clear();
        people.ForEach(p => _bsPeople.Add(p));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение окна редактирования чела
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var editForm = new EditForm())
        {
            editForm.Owner = this;
            editForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

            //выбранный в таблице чел
            var selectedPerson = _bsPeople.Current as Person;

            //создаем редактируемую копию
            editForm.CurrentPerson = new Person
            {
                Id = selectedPerson.Id,
                FirstName = selectedPerson.FirstName,
                LastName = selectedPerson.LastName
            };

            //отображаем форму и ждем результат
            editForm.Text = $"Редактирование {selectedPerson.FirstName} {selectedPerson.LastName}";
            if (editForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //изменяем данные в БД
                Program.Context.UpdatePerson(editForm.CurrentPerson);

                //перезагружаем данные в таблицу
                LoadData();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Т.е. не нужно перезагружать форму, а нужно перезагружать данные из базы в случае если пользователь нажал кнопку OK

Comment: Ого, думаю это то, что нужно. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Пожалуйста, если что-то непонятно, то пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/JkHhF5kUYiQTCQ)

Comment: @Nephilim я немного дописал в этот пример удаление и добавление нового человека, а также валидацию пользовательского ввода. Посмотрите этот [пример](https://yadi.sk/d/tySDR3ZG-v1_UA)

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Я как раз делаю что-то на подобии этого, и самая большая проблема была как раз в "обновлении" данных после их изменения...